# How to make dynamic progress bars with javascript

Tags: javascript, progress-bar

problem with make an animated dynamic scroll bars with javascript

I tried to make a dynamic animated progress bars with which it will run when i reach to a specific div by using onscroll event but i can't reach to my goal because i feel there is a conflict here between the for loop and the setInterval event!

```
    //HTML
    <div class="skills_bars">
        <div class="meter">
            <span></span>
            <span class="number">10</span>
        </div>
        <div class="meter">
            <span></span>
            <span class="number">10</span>
        </div>
        <div class="meter">
            <span></span>
            <span class="number">10</span>
        </div>
        <div class="meter">
            <span></span>
            <span class="number">10</span>
        </div>

    </div>


    //CSS 
 .skills_bars .meter{
   width: 100%;
   background: #000000;
   height: 11px;
   position: relative;
   display: block;
   margin-bottom:60px;
 }

.skills_bars .meter span:first- 
of-type{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 10%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #FC4444;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;

}

.skills_bars .meter span.number{
  position: absolute;
  right: 3px;
  top: -29px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

    //JS CODE
    var progressMeter = document.querySelectorAll(".skills_bars 
                        .meter span:first-of-type");
    var progressNumber = document.querySelectorAll('.skills_bars 
                         .meter span.number');
    var progressNumberWidths = [50,90,80,20];

    window.addEventListener("scroll", progressNumberAdd);

    function progressNumberAdd(){
        if (pageYOffset > (progressMeter[0].offsetTop - 600)){
            window.removeEventListener("scroll", 
            progressNumberAdd);
            for(var i = 0; i < progressMeter.length; i++){
                        x(i);
            }
        }
    }

    function x(i){
        var move = setInterval(numberAddCheker(i), 15);
    }

    var width = 0;
    function numberAddCheker(i){

        if(width >= progressNumberWidths[i]){
            clearInterval(move)
        }else{
            width++;
            console.log(width)
            progressMeter[i].style.width = width + "%";
            progressNumber[i].textContent = width * 1 + "%" ;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with your code, primarily on this line `setInterval(numberAddCheker(i), 15)`, `setInterval` requires a callback, here you are executing the `numberAddChecker`. You can pass parameters on callback function on  `setInterval` like this `setInterval(numberAddCheker, 15, i)`.

You are clearing interval with `move`, but it's not a global variable, it's declared inside so when eventually `numberAddCheker` is executed `move` will be undefined, also you are just clearing interval of the last item.

You have to save all intervals on an array, and clear them based on their index.

Here is a complete solution put together -

```js
var progressMeter = document.querySelectorAll(".skills_bars .meter span:first-of-type");
    var progressNumber = document.querySelectorAll('.skills_bars .meter span.number');
    var progressNumberWidths = [50,90,80,20];
    var moveTimers = [];
    var width = 0;
    window.addEventListener("scroll", progressNumberAdd);

    function progressNumberAdd(){
        if (window.pageYOffset > (progressMeter[0].offsetTop - 600)){
            window.removeEventListener("scroll", progressNumberAdd);
            initProgressBar();
        }
    }
    
    function initProgressBar(){
      for(var i = 0; i < progressMeter.length; i++){
        x(i);     
      }   
    }

    function x(i){
        moveTimers[i] = setInterval(numberAddCheker, 15, i);
    }
    
    function numberAddCheker(i){
        if(width >= progressNumberWidths[i]){
            clearInterval(moveTimers[i])
        }else{
            width++;
            progressMeter[i].style.width = width + "%";
            progressNumber[i].textContent = width * 1 + "%" ;
        }
    }
```

```css
 .skills_bars .meter{
   width: 100%;
   background: #000000;
   height: 11px;
   position: relative;
   display: block;
   margin-bottom:60px;
 }
body{
  background: #ccc;
}
.skills_bars .meter span:first-of-type{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 10%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #FC4444;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;

}

.skills_bars .meter span.number{
  position: absolute;
  right: 3px;
  top: -29px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
   <div class="skills_bars" style="margin-top: 100vh">
        <div class="meter">
            <span></span>
            <span class="number">10</span>
        </div>
        <div class="meter">
            <span></span>
            <span class="number">10</span>
        </div>
        <div class="meter">
            <span></span>
            <span class="number">10</span>
        </div>
        <div class="meter">
            <span></span>
            <span class="number">10</span>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Note. I moved the for loop into a separate function for clarity, you can keep it as it is on your code.
Just an FYI, scroll to see the progress bars.

Comment: thanks bro for your answer it's really help and it run as i want, i just want to ask you the best way or online resources to become good js developer for front end web developing

Comment: @ShadyAgmy glad it helped. There is no definitive best resource to learn JavaScript, for up to date documentation MDN is the best. Check https://javascript30.com/ for quality video lessons. You can get an idea of things you need to learn to become a front-end developer here https://github.com/kamranahmedse/developer-roadmap. Learn the basics and practice a lot. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't had the css that you are using so I have used my own css and done some minor changes not logic and seems it is working. Please find the code below  and let me know if it works for you.
Changes done :

1. Added css
2. Added progressMeter[i].style.backgroundColor = "blue";
3. Changed scroll to click (Need to be changed)

Note: I have tested this with click only as I am facing with scroller in my system Please test with scroll event and let me know.

Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>To test progress bar</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .skills_bars {
            width: 280px;
            height: 5px;
        }
        .skills_bars .meter {
            display: inline-block;
            height: 5px;
            width: 200px;
            background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238);
            position: relative;
        }

        .skills_bars .meter span{
            display: inline-block;
            height: 5px;
            float: left;
        }
    </style>
 </head>
 <body>
     <div class="skills_bars">
         <div class="meter">
             <span "></span>
             <span class="number">10</span>
         </div>
         <div class="meter">
             <span></span>
             <span class="number">10</span>
         </div>
         <div class="meter">
             <span ></span>
             <span class="number">10</span>
         </div>
         <div class="meter">
             <span ></span>
             <span class="number">10</span>
         </div>
     </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    //JS CODE
        var progressMeter = document.querySelectorAll(".skills_bars .meter span:first-of-type");
        var progressNumber = document.querySelectorAll('.skills_bars .meter span.number');
        var progressNumberWidths = [50,90,80,20];

        window.addEventListener("click", progressNumberAdd);

        function progressNumberAdd(){
            if (pageYOffset > (progressMeter[0].offsetTop - 600)){
                window.removeEventListener("scroll", progressNumberAdd);
                for(var i = 0; i < progressMeter.length; i++){
                    x(i);
                }
            }
        }

        function x(i){

            var move = setInterval(numberAddCheker(i), 15);
        }

        var width = 0;
        function numberAddCheker(i){

            if(width >= progressNumberWidths[i]){
                clearInterval(move)
            }else{
                width++;
                console.log(width)
                progressMeter[i].style.width = width + "%";
                progressMeter[i].style.backgroundColor = "blue";

                progressNumber[i].textContent = width * 1 + "%" ;
            }
        }      
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I added my css code above, thanks for your answer but i think it didn't solve the problem and i mean with the onscroll event that when the user scroll to skills_bars section the function progressNumberAdd will run and all the code below it will run also